# Can't tell if Vue project is in debug more or release mode for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, vue.js, release

I'm building this Vue app with Visual Studio and regardless of the build mode (debug/release) I still get this message below in the console.

> You are running Vue in development mode.
>   Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
>   See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

Is there a way to know if I'm really in release mode or if Vue is just throwing me that message?

I know that usually it means the JS files have been minified, is that the case with a Vue app?

I'm not sure if this helps but here is my packages.json file

```js
{
  "name": "aspnetcore-vuejs",
  "description": "ASP.NET Core & VueJS Starter project",
  "author": "Mark Pieszak",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development NODE_ENV=development dotnet run",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules",
    "install": "webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.3.1",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.11",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.7.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^3.0.3",
    "vue": "^2.1.8",
    "vue-infinite-loading": "^2.3.3",
    "vue-masked-input": "^0.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^2.1.1",
    "vue-select": "^2.5.0",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.1.8",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.1.8",
    "vuetify": "^1.2.3",
    "vuex": "^2.1.1",
    "vuex-router-sync": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "cross-env": "^3.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "event-source-polyfill": "^0.0.7",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.1.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.12.1",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "vue-loader": "^10.0.2",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: What script did you run? (in package.json)

Comment: Not sure! This was a former co workers project that I've inherited. How can I check? I'll post the packages.json file.

Answer (score 0):

As the [Vue.js deployment guide](https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html) you posted suggests, please check your `webpack.config.js` and be sure to use the right `mode` targetting [`production`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/#mode-production) environment when you deploy the app.

In Webpack 4+, you can do:

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production'
}
```

But in Webpack 3 and earlier, you'll need to use [`DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/):

```js
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    // ...
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    })
  ]
}
```

When you are ready, you should simply need to run `npm run build` to start bundling your modules.

---

Related and useful readings:

- [Writing **separate Webpack configurations** for each environment](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#setup).
- [Managing development and production builds with Webpack](https://atendesigngroup.com/blog/managing-dev-and-production-builds-webpack).
- [Introduction to NPM Scripts](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/introduction-to-npm-scripts-1dbb2ae01633).